# Can I use datashader methods over bokeh figure?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, data-analysis, datashader

I have a bokeh figure object. This object represents a map which is plotted with millions of points. I want to use `datashader` for this figure. How can I do it? I know there is `InteractiveImage` in bokeh extension of `datashader`.
similarly is there any `datashader` extension for bokeh?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no datashader extension for bokeh itself.  Instead, we have provided datashader support in [HoloViews](http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Large_Data.html).  The higher-level interface of HoloViews makes it possible to implement the dynamic behavior required by Datashader much more cleanly than we could do within Bokeh itself, while providing a fully functional Bokeh plot as the result.